# Concatenate certain letters in a string

Tags: list, python-2.7, string-concatenation

I have been using this stackoverflow for years, but have never posted questions personally. I hope my first question is not too naive.

I am trying to do some concatenation in a string. Let's say I have a string

```
string = "C S E majors in U S"
```

I want to make this string that looks something like

```
string = "CSE majors in US"
```

I thought about doing it by splitting the string into list, loop it, and check whether the element has a length equals to 1. If it has, check for next ones iteratively, and combine them at the end.

I was wondering whether there are better approaches to this. Since I am pretty new to python, it will be very nice to have some illustrations with codes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.

```
>>> ' '.join((' ' if pred else '').join(seq) for pred, seq in itertools.groupby("C S E majors in U S".split(), lambda x: len(x) > 1))
'CSE majors in US'
```

Comment: Wow! that's amazingly short code! Thanks! I will try to dissect this code to understand what's going on.